# call onLeft in Component React native router flux

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, react-native-router-flux

I've used React Native Router Flux for my project. How can I trigger onRight function on the Welcome component? I just only can call function on NavigationController class.

```
 export default class NavigationController extends Component {

        render() {
            return (

                <Drawer
                    ...>
                    <Router>
                        <Scene key="root">
                            <Scene key="intro" passProps={true} drawer={this} hideNavBar={true} component={Intro}
                                   initial={true}/>
                            <Scene key="welcome"
                                   component={Welcome}
                                   onRight={() => alert("right")}
                                   rightButtonImage={require('./assets/plus_blue.png')}
                                   />
                        </Scene>
                    </Router>
                </Drawer>

            );
        }
    }
```